# SSIS Extracting Just A First Name From Full Name

Tags: excel, ssis, expression

Still new to SSIS, but I've run into a problem while trying to load an excel file into my database.  I'm trying to load the first name then last name into my database table, but the excel file is set up a bit weird for some reason.

This is an example of what the excel file looks like
**Excel File**

```html
First Name    Last Name
----------    ---------
Jason         Doe
 Derek M      Smith
 John L       Doe
 Carol        Smith
```

So, every entry after the first has a blank space in it for some reason, also some entries have a middle initial included in the first name and some do not.

What I'm trying to do is extract just the first name and leave the middle initial out.

What I have it doing currently is just trim the blank space from the excel file which looks like this.

```html
TRIM([Member First Name])

**OUTPUT** 
Jason
Derek M
John L
Carol
```

When I try to experiment with cutting out the middle initial, I start running into problems.

```html
 SUBSTRING(TRIM(FULLNAME),1,FINDSTRING(TRIM(FULLNAME)," ",1))
 
 **OUTPUT**
 
 Derek
 John
 ​
```

So, this way cuts out the initial, but only displays entries who have a middle initial, and leaves entries that do not have an initial, blank.

Moving the `TRIM` around either leaves the column blank or just displays the first letter of their first name.

What can I do to just extract the first name from this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derived column expression should be like this :

```
FINDSTRING(TRIM(FULLNAME)," ",1) == 0 ? FULLNAME : SUBSTRING(TRIM(FULLNAME),1,FINDSTRING(TRIM(FULLNAME)," ",1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your current `SUBSTRING...` in a ternary expression (aka an in-line IF) so that it only does the `SUBSTRING...` if there is a space in the TRIMMED value.  ELSE it just does the TRIM.

Here is a psuedocode outline of how it should look:

```
{Condition} ? {Value if True} : {Value if False}

{Condition} is a test that will be TRUE if the trimmed string contains a blank space, and false if it doesn't.   The FINDSTRING() function should be useful here.

{Value if True} can simply be the current SUBSTRING(...) that you have in your last code snippet.

{Value if False} can simply be the TRIM(...) that you have in your second-to-last code snippet.
```

Comment: Thanks, I have no experience using a conditional split inside the derived columns.  I tried reading up on it, but couldn't wrap my head around it. So, I'd need the original `Substring(Trim(FULLNAME)...` first, then set it equal to something, then the `?` and then the if/else outcomes?

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the trimmed result to see if 2 spaces back is blank. This avoids complex names like Ann Lee.

```
substring(  trim([First name]),len(trim([First name]))-2,1)   ==" " ? substring(trim([First name]),1, len(trim([First name]))-3) : trim([First name])
```